# Set defauls value for DecimalField as 0.00

Tags: django, forms, decimal

I'm trying to have the default value for several DecimalFields defined as `0.00` in my model class, but even when I have this:

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, 
               default=Decimal(0.00))
```

I'm getting an error when processing the form:

```
ValidationError
[u'This value must be a decimal number.']
```

From the error page, I can see that the issue is that the save method gets `u''` for the empty fields.  How can I have 0.00 being stored?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put quotes around the number:

```
Decimal('0.00')
```

Comment: Thanks :)  gotta remember that.  I'd also overwritten some of the fields in forms.py and set them as CharFields, hence the u'' for some.  Can't believe I'd overlooked that.

Comment: Eyyy, no worries! If I had a dollar for everything seemingly simple I've overlooked... I'd have a lot of dollars. At least a fistful.

Comment: I am using Django 1.3 and it accepts unquoted values just fine .ie default = Decimal(0.00)